# Rails validates NOT in regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a Rails 3 validation that will ensure that people are not using one of the common free email addresses.

My thought was something like this ....

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^((?!gmail).*)$|^((?!yahoo).*)$|^((?!hotmail).*)$/
```

or

```
validates_exclusion_of :email, :in => %w( gmail. GMAIL. hotmail. HOTMAIL. live. LIVE. aol. AOL. ), :message => "You must use your corporate email address."
```

But neither works properly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you've written a regex that matches anything. Let's break it down.

```
/
  ^(            # [ beginning of string
    (?!gmail)   #   followed by anything other than "gmail"
    .           #   followed by any one character
  )$            #   followed by the end the of string
  |             # ] OR [
  ^(            #   beginning of the string
    (?!yahoo)   #   followed by anything other than "yahoo"
    .           #   followed by any one character
  )$            #   followed by the end of the string
  |             # ] OR [
  ^(            #   beginning of the string
    (?!hotmail) #   followed by anything other than "hotmail"
    .*          #   followed by any or no characters 
  )$            #   followed by the end the of string
/               # ]
```

When you think about it you'll realize that the only strings that won't match are ones that start with "gmail," "yahoo," *and* "hotmail"--all at the same time, which is impossible.

What you really want is something like this:

```
/
  .+@                      # one or more characters followed by @
  (?!                      # followed by anything other than...
    (gmail|yahoo|hotmail)  # [ one of these strings
    \.                     #   followed by a literal dot
  )                        # ]
  .+                       # followed by one or more characters
  $                        # and the end of the string
/i                         # case insensitive
```

Put it together and you have:

```ruby
expr = /.+@(?!(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)\.).+$/i

test_cases = %w[ foo@gmail.com
                 bar@yahoo.com
                 BAZ@HOTMAIL.COM
                 qux@example.com
                 quux
               ]

test_cases.map {|addr| expr =~ addr }
# => [nil, nil, nil, 0, nil]
#    (nil means no match, 0 means there was a match starting at character 0)
```

Comment: I see the problem you explained with my regex.  But I've tried validates_format_of :email, :with => /.+@(?!(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)\.).+$/i but it doesn't seem to work so far.

Comment: I tested your regex and it looks like it should work.  I'm thinking I now have a problem with the syntax on my rails validation.

Comment: My validation wasn't firing in certain instances (if I had a child model).  That was just a bad coincidence.  Your code was perfect.